# Can not access to content script object methods

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Goal:
   show page info by using Youtube object that is defined in content script "Youtube.js"

Problem:
   can not access members.

I have the following script which is also registered in manifest.cs under content_scripts:

```
/// <reference path="UtilityFunctions.js" />
var playerElementId = "movie_player";
var youtube = new Youtube();

writePageInfo(youtube);

function Youtube() //ctor
{ 
   this.playerObj = getPlayer();
} 

Youtube.prototype.IsCurrentSite = function ()
{
  var url = location.href;

  if (url.indexOf("youtube.com") > 0)
  {
    return playerObj != null;
  }

  return false;
}

function getPlayer()
{
   return document.getElementById(playerElementId);
}

//debug
function writePageInfo(youtubeObj)
{
   //alert("From Youtube content script"); //this line is executed
   alert("Youtube - debug: " + youtubeObj.IsCurrentSite()); //this line NOT: undefined function
}
```

I do not know what to do to write the uncommented alert message.

P.S.:
  if I open several Youtube pages several objects will be created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing but the reason for the error is that you are creating and using an instance of `Youtube` constructor and then you are adding a method to its prototype. This new method (i.e. `IsCurrentSite`) does not exists when you pass the `youtube` object to `writePageInfo` function.

To fix this, you need to call `writePageInfo(youtube)` **AFTER** adding the method to the prototype:

```
var youtube = new Youtube();
Youtube.prototype.IsCurrentSite = function ()
{
  var url = location.href;

  if (url.indexOf("youtube.com") > 0)
  {
    return playerObj != null;
  }

  return false;
}

writePageInfo(youtube); //moved here
```

Answering your question, each browser tab (or window) has its own JavaScript environment.

Comment: Conceptually at least, it's better to move it all the way up. You will then define how an object behaves before creating an instance of it.